# Tensorflow Estimator: How to run an operation within model_fn

Tags: python, tensorflow

I got a very short question, which has probably a very simple answer but I just can't figure it out, although I tried for hours now.

I'm using Tensorflow Estimator and I want to access the global step within my model_fn. I've tried tf.train.get_global_step, which returns me a Tensor. I need the global_step as an integer though (or as a string)!

So I've tried to eval() (= tf.get_default_session().run(t)), but it doesn't work..

Cheers!

Comment: did you ever find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.cast to cast the `Tensor` to `int` or `string`.

For example,

```
tf.cast(tf.train.get_global_step(), dtype=tf.int)
```

See the reference [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast).

Comment: I don't think this should work as the Tensor of the global_step needs to be run within a session to return its value. Have you tested it?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to parse it from the latest checkpoint file in the `model_dir`.
So assuming you can pass the `model_dir` into the `model_fn` (either through the `params` argument of `tf.estimator.Estimator(..., params={'model_dir': 'path/to/model_dir'})` or through `tf.flags.FLAGS`, you can then use this utility function:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def get_global_step_from_model_dir(model_dir):
    latest_checkpoint_file = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_dir)
    if latest_checkpoint_file is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return int(os.path.basename(latest_checkpoint_file).split('-')[-1])
```